# Powershell Mount-VHD weird behavior when issued remotely

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, hypervisor

If i run the below code on the hyper-v hypervisor (locally), it runs successfully and i get the correct Drive-Letter.

```
$DriveLetter = (Mount-VHD "F:\Template\win2016Template.vhdx" -PassThru | 
Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
```

output: G

but if i modify it to run from any normal domain joined workstation using domain admin privileges i got incorrect Drive-Letter

```
$DriveLetter = (Mount-VHD -ComputerName RUF-HV01 "F:\Template\win2016Template.vhdx" -PassThru | Get- 
Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
```

output: T

I have no idea where "T" is coming from. The correct drive letter is G not T.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Why is G the "correct" drive letter? When you mount the drive with Mount-VHD, I think it just chooses the next free letter. I'm unaware of a way to specify a particular drive letter to use with powershell, although DISM can do it.

Comment: @DustyVargas Because this is the correct drive letter that is showing in "My Computer"

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When you mount a vhd, it will be assigned a drive letter automatically. It is not guaranteed to be the same letter every time.